# Is there a way to fetch the DynamoDB attribute name if we know the attribute name of the entity class?

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb, aws-java-sdk, aws-java-sdk-dynamodb

Given a DynamoDB entity like this

```
@Data()
@DynamoDBTable(tableName = "DynamoTable")
public class DynamoTable implements Serializable {
    @DynamoDBAttribute(attributeName = "DATA_VALUE")
    private String data

    …
}
```

What I want to know is if I know the name of the attribute in the entity class (`data`), could I get the name of the DynamoDB attribute it is annotated with in the entity class (`DATA_VALUE`)?

Comment: I did not get your question please elaborate on your result? Give an example or something

Answer (score 1):

It can be simply achieved with [reflection](http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-reflection/index.html):

```java
final Field field = DynamoTable.class.getField("data");
final DynamoDBAttribute annotation = field.getAnnotation(DynamoDBAttribute.class);

if(null != annotation) {
    System.out.println(annotation.attributeName());
}
```